# How to implement Sliding Panel in UWP?

Tags: xamarin, window, mvvmcross, uwp-xaml

I have created AppShell Page as a master page for my mvvmcross UWP(windows 10) app and added hamburger menu in it. Now I want to add two buttons like Users and Customers in hamburger menu. When click on users button i want to open sliding panel from right side with animation and display list in it and when user click anywhere in page except sliding layout then hide sliding layout.

Please suggest me any good way to achieve this.

Thank you.

Comment: I added stack panel on right side of AppShell page and add back button on top of stack panel to hide it when click on back button. But i don't think it is a good way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Easy - use a `TranslateTransform` to animate sliding and `Visibility` to make it show up or hide.

Comment: <SplitView PanePlacement="Right"> work for me as per my requirement.